# Category Theory after CatsNSheaves

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, higher-category-theory

I’m currently reading MacLane’s “Categories for the Working Mathematician” and am loving it. So I bought a copy of Kashiwara & Schapira’s “Categories and Sheaves” and plan to tackle that next.

My question is, where can one go after Cats n Sheaves? More specifically, where in pure category theory? Is the only place to go higher category, or is there still a lot of interesting/important 1-category theory to learn?

If I come across overly ignorant, my apologies.

Comment: I have had a copy of Cats & Sheaves for a while, but right now I'm preferring *Handbook of Categorical Algebra* volumes 2 & 3.

Comment: What about those books do you prefer to Cats & Sheaves?

Comment: Borceux's book is easier to understand while still covering the advanced topics.   Cats and Sheaves has a "different way" of explaining things that is non-standard.  For example, you won't find the mention of "cone" in the limits chapter.  I recommend getting both books and seeing which one you like more after the first 30 pages.

Answer (score 5):

There's lots of other 1-dimensional category theory to study, although just as you can only get so far in algebra or topology without any category theory, eventually 2-category theory at the very least will inevitably begin to make its presence felt.

On topos theory, which connects to logic but also to algebraic geometry: *Sheaves in geometry and logic* by Maclane & Moerdijk, *Topoi: the categorial analysis of logic* by Goldblatt. Goldblatt is easier and pitched more at the philosophically minded.

Beyond a book on topos theory, the key intermediate book on category theory I'd suggest to anybody developing a more serious interest is *Elements of Enriched Category Theory* by Kelly. It's unfortunately the only book Kelly ever wrote, although dozens of his papers remain highly recommended. A great book on categories sufficiently more general than topoi to capture almost every single important large category is *Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories* by Adamek and Rosicky.

An area of application of topos theory which many find quite intriguing is synthetic differential geometry, which studies how to formalize calculus with a "real line" which contains infinitesimal elements, without destroying classical differential geometric results. Anders Kock has a couple of introductory-level books here.

This is semi-secretly moving towards higher category theory, but *Categorical Homotopy Theory* by Riehl is a great introduction to another major application area, and works primarily with ordinary categories.

Another direction to go in is homological algebra. Freyd's *Abelian Categories* and Gelfand-Manin's *Triangulated Categories* are nice introductions to certain aspects of this field.

A somewhat off-the-beaten-path topoic is categorical universal algebra. For a treatment of a moderately generalized form of classical universal algebra from a categorical viewpoint, see *Algebraic categories* by Adamek, Rosicky, and Vitale; for an impressive categorical study of certain algebraic categories which had previously only been well understood in classical universal algebraic temrs, see *Malt'sev, Homological, and Protomodular categories*, by Borceux and Bourn, probably after studying abelian categories.

Finally, while *Categories and Sheaves* is a good book, it's very difficult and would be quite a ways down my list of next books for you, unless you have a very specific reason to go in that direction. I also agree with BananaCats about Borceux.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response! I don’t have a specific reason for wanting to read Categories & Sheaves other than hearing great things about it and being interested in its treatment of homological algebra. Those recommendations sound great; I’m planning on taking courses in algebraic geometry and topology next year.

Comment:  I love that you mentioned me.

Comment: @BananaCats it's a fun name to get to type.